# API for dynatrace Managed version dashboard

Tags: dynatrace

Created a dynatrace dashboard with latest Dynatrace Managed version 1.50, need the API to fetch the dashboard for specific duration.
Also the link accessed for other browser is asking credentials

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is currently no API to fetch data for a complete Dashboard.

There is an API to fetch timeseries-data, see the [documentation for timeseries API](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/dynatrace-api/environment/timeseries-api/read-data-points-of-metrics-via-api/), by repeatedely invoking this one for each of the metrics that are shown in the dashboard, you should be able to fetch all the data.

The the credentials in API calls, make sure to properly include the authorization token, see the [documentation for how to authenticate](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/dynatrace-api/dynatrace-api-authentication/) for more details.